# What is the argument for dissolution of the branch structure of the wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-information

I have come across a Quantum Foundations talk by a former/current member of SE (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_B8sub-8CU&t=13s)).

After discussing modern developments towards making a more precise notion of branch structure of the universal wavefunction (along the lines of [Consistent Histories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_histories) as I understand), he refers to the idea that thermalisation (at the end of the universe) will lead to a "dissolution of this branch structure".

I could not find any reference to this term. What does it mean and what is the argument that this will occur?